# cannot pass a generic type from a new instance of a class into the class method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, generics

Trying to create a generic class to be able to reduce redundancy in my c# code, I have 4 classes that more or less use the same methods (add, get, edit, delete) However when I am querying my db via entity framework I am getting this error. "cannot vert from 'T' to 'SneakerDrop.Domain.Models.User' and that 'T' does not contain properties of UserId

I have converted the class out of static, to be able to create a new instance in program, to test if it is because I am trying to pass a new datatype via xUnit.

```
public class Program
{
    public User user = new User
    {
        UserId = 1,
        Username = "ian2519",
        Password = "Password",
        Firstname = "Ian",
        Lastname = "Nai",
        Email = "Email@email.com"
    };

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        UserHelper<User> test = new UserHelper<User>();
        Program program = new Program();

        test.AddUser(program.user);
    }




public class UserHelper<T>
{
 private SneakerDropDbContext _db = new SneakerDropDbContext();

    public bool AddUser(T user)
    {
        _db.Users.Add(user);
        return _db.SaveChanges() == 1;

    }
    public T GetUserInfoById(T user)
    {
        T dbInfo = _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

        return dbInfo;
    }
    public bool EditUserInfoById(T user)
    {
        var results = _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

        results.Username = user.Username;
        results.Firstname = user.Firstname;
        results.Lastname = user.Lastname;
        results.Password = user.Password;
        results.Email = user.Email;

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
}
```

getting error that T cannot convert from T on _db.USers.Add(user)
and getting T does not contain definition for Username, Firstname, etc..
on lines results.Username, results.Firstname...

Comment: Generic class of userhelper it is common for insert, update, here you want access model information then need to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

This class serves little purpose of being generic and would need to be constrained to something.

If you could make it generic you would need to constraint it to `User` (since you have shown no interfaces or sub-classes) which would make any generic plumbing redundant. If you feel you need a helper class in this case, just use the standard types.

```
public class UserHelper
{

   public bool AddUser(User user)
   {
      _db.Users.Add(user);
      return _db.SaveChanges() == 1;

   }
   public User GetUserInfoById(User user)
   {
      User dbInfo = _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

      return dbInfo;
   }
   public bool EditUserInfoById(User user)
   {
      var results = _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

      results.Username = user.Username;
      results.Firstname = user.Firstname;
      results.Lastname = user.Lastname;
      results.Password = user.Password;
      results.Email = user.Email;

      _db.SaveChanges();

      return true;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
UserHelper test = new UserHelper();
test.AddUser(program.user);
```

What it seems like you are trying to do is to make a generic repository over EF, which is just hiding useful methods behind a layer of abstraction, complicating a well written framework and making your development more problematic. I would advise against it strongly unless you have a very specific need.